# Running angular_components with Dart SDK 2.1.0-dev

Tags: angular-dart

I have installed the latest Dart SDK 2.1.0-dev.7.1 to try out Material design examples:
https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/tree/master/examples

The sample that fails in the following is:

```
angular_components/examples/material_card_example
```

I have git cloned the repo and when running `webdev serve` in one of the samples I get:

```
webdev could not run for this project.
You must have a dependency on `build_runner` in `pubspec.yaml`.
# pubspec.yaml
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: >=0.8.10 <2.0.0
You must have a dependency on `build_web_compilers` in `pubspec.yaml`.
# pubspec.yaml
dev_dependencies:
  build_web_compilers: >=0.3.6 <0.5.0
```

Do you know how to run the samples?

Comment: "one of the samples" which one was that?

Comment: The material_card_example

Comment: Google uses a bit different tools internally, this might be the reason this does not work on your system, or these examples are just not meant to be run individually. https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/tree/master/examples/angular_components_example contains `build_runner` and `build_web_compilers` and should not produce the error you posted. I think stagehand should be up-to-date for Angular as well, but haven't tried it for a long time.

Comment: Thanks I think I will wait for the released version - hope they keep pushing this forward :-)

Comment: "released version" of what? Angular examples?

Comment: Dart 2.1.x Thinking that they will update the examples along with Dart.

Comment: As far as I know all things you mentioned are updated only incrementally currently, also Dart 2.x. There are currently no bigger changes expected anywhere. If you're missing something I think it's best to create an issue in the respective GitHub repo.

Comment: Ok, thank you very mush for info - I will try just that

Comment: Created issue https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/issues/347

Comment: Yes, that is me